# Read Excel file from OneDrive / Sharepoint - error code: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, openpyxl

I am trying to read an excel file from SharePoint to python and my first error message was that I should define an engine manually, so I defined the engine = 'openpyxl' and now the following error message comes up: *File is not a ZIP File*

From the previous Q&As it was often talked about if the Excel - file is a real Excel file or some text file with a fake xlsx extension.

The excel file was created using Microsoft Excel and its stored in a shared OneDrive folder (Team - Sharepoint). Does it affect the error message?

How can i solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 

url_sp = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/TeamE'
username_sp = 'MyUsername'
password_sp = 'MyPassword'
folder_url_sp = '/Shared%20Documents/02%20Team%20IAP/06_Da-An/Data/E/Edate.xlsx'

#Authentication
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url_sp)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username_sp, password_sp):
    ctx = ClientContext(url_sp, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print('Authentication sucessfull')

else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
    
import io 

response = File.open_binary(ctx,folder_url_sp)

bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) 

data = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj,sheet_name = None, engine = 'openpyxl')
```

The Error:

````
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 32
     29 bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
     30 bytes_file_obj.seek(0) 
---> 32 data = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name= None, engine = 'openpyxl')

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:457, in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, decimal, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    455 if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    456     should_close = True
--> 457     io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    458 elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    459     raise ValueError(
    460         "Engine should not be specified when passing "
    461         "an ExcelFile - ExcelFile already has the engine set"
    462     )

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1419, in ExcelFile.__init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1416 self.engine = engine
   1417 self.storage_options = storage_options
-> 1419 self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:525, in OpenpyxlReader.__init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    514 """
    515 Reader using openpyxl engine.
    516 
   (...)
    522     passed to fsspec for appropriate URLs (see ``_get_filepath_or_buffer``)
    523 """
    524 import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 525 super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:518, in BaseExcelReader.__init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    516 self.handles.handle.seek(0)
    517 try:
--> 518     self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    519 except Exception:
    520     self.close()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:536, in OpenpyxlReader.load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    533 def load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer: FilePath | ReadBuffer[bytes]):
    534     from openpyxl import load_workbook
--> 536     return load_workbook(
    537         filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    538     )

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:315, in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    288 def load_workbook(filename, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
    289                   data_only=False, keep_links=True):
    290     """Open the given filename and return the workbook
    291 
    292     :param filename: the path to open or a file-like object
   (...)
    313 
    314     """
--> 315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
    317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:124, in ExcelReader.__init__(self, fn, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    122 def __init__(self,  fn, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
    123               data_only=False, keep_links=True):
--> 124     self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
    125     self.valid_files = self.archive.namelist()
    126     self.read_only = read_only

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py:96, in _validate_archive(filename)
     89             msg = ('openpyxl does not support %s file format, '
     90                    'please check you can open '
     91                    'it with Excel first. '
     92                    'Supported formats are: %s') % (file_format,
     93                                                    ','.join(SUPPORTED_FORMATS))
     94         raise InvalidFileException(msg)
---> 96 archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
     97 return archive

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py:1266, in ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1264 try:
   1265     if mode == 'r':
-> 1266         self._RealGetContents()
   1267     elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1268         # set the modified flag so central directory gets written
   1269         # even if no files are added to the archive
   1270         self._didModify = True

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py:1333, in ZipFile._RealGetContents(self)
   1331     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1332 if not endrec:
-> 1333     raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1334 if self.debug > 1:
   1335     print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

```
````

Comment: Have you tried open an xlsx file locally, using the same `open_binary` code? ie break the problem down into smaller tests. eg can you open the file directly using read_excel?

Comment: Yes, if I have saved it locally, and it opens it without problems. As soon as it is saved in a OneDrive folder, the error messages appear, but i  need the OneDrive file because several people need to access it. @DS_London